# Determine object's tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, field, forms

Suppose I have a jQuery object, say it is field of a form and I query it by id:

```
$("#my_field")
```

How can I determine the tag of that object, in particular: is it label or input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName) property on a `DOM` object

Accessing jQuery object by index gives you the `DOM` object.

```
$('#my_field')[0].tagName
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/XrDgG/)**